# React Router V4 - Storing location in external store

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to figure out how to store the current location in an external store (in this case MobX), but I can't figure out how to hook into the router to update the store when the path changes as well.

Comment: https://github.com/alisd23/mobx-react-router

Comment: @free-soul it doesn't look like that supports v4 since you don't manually specify history + no on change hooks.

Comment: this looks like it should work well, https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router-addons-controlled